# Android: Getting row by id

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I'm trying to get database row by it's ID, but somehow query doesn't return that row. The sql query `SELECT * From Table1 Where _id = 100` works good, so I don't know what's the reason. Here is the code of the query:

```
    String [] selectedArgs = new String [] {String.valueOf(selectedItemId)};
    String selection = Tables.Table1.COLUMN_ID + "=?";
    String [] columns = {Tables.Table1.COLUMN_ID, Tables.Table1.COLUMN_NAME};
    Cursor c = foodDB.query(Tables.Food.TABLE_NAME, columns, selection, selectedArgs, null, null, null);
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: you're just getting a different sql row? have you tried logging `selectedItemId` to see what its contents actually hold?

Comment: yes, it's content is usual long numbers like 1, 100 etc.

Comment: When you leave out the `selection`, you get all records. Does this include some record with the desired ID?

Comment: Yes, it includes a record with the desired ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody need it, i have used rawQuery() method for such type of query to work, because query() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your ID field is a number, while the parameter is a string; the `query` function does not allow other parameter types for some strange reason.

Try using an expression like `COLUMN_ID + " = CAST(? AS INTEGER)"`.

If your query had only one result column, you could use a separate [`SQLiteStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) object where you'd be able to use `bindLong()`.

Comment: Can you please post the example for this SQLiteStatement? How can I use it?

Comment: It returns position -1, the same result as "_ID=?"

Comment: This happens when there are no records in the cursor.

Comment: Yes, but the record with this id exists.